# How to sum django model fields

Tags: django

```
class Salary() :
    Basic = models. IntegerField () 
    Allowance = models. IntegerField () 
    Incentivies = models.  IntegerField () 
    gross = models. IntegerField () 
    gratuity = models. IntegerField () 
     Ctc = models. IntegerField ()
```

Here my problem is
gross = basic+ allowance+ incentives

ctc= gross+gratuity

How should I sum for that, no need to enter the value of gross or ctc. It should sum

Comment: If the sum always holds, typically it is better *not* to make fields for these, but perform annotations, since now you introduce *data duplication*.

Comment: see this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation

Comment: In addition to @WillemVanOnsem maybe you can also consider having a `custom model manager` that will `annotate` ctc.

Comment: is there any way to do pre_save .i don't know how to do that, through pre_save it may work right ..can you give one some examples for pre_save

Comment: @BTR: some calls like `Saraly.objects.update(basic=12)` *circumvent* the signals, and thus then the `gross` is no longer in sync with the fields. Typically signals are not a good idea, and a last resort if all else is not possible.

Answer (score 7):

If the sum always holds, it is better *not* to make fields for these. Indeed, by making fields, this can result in the fact that certain updates could break the constraint. Yes, Django has signals, etc. that can be triggered when you save a model, but some ORM calls, like `.update(..)` circumvent these signals.

It is usually better to annotate in case the sum always holds. This means that there are no explicit fields in the database, but that you instruct the database to calculate the fields when necessary. This thus saves diskspace for the database, and furthermore it makes it impossible that the relation does not hold.

We can define an annotation manager as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class AnnotationManager(models.Manager):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.annotations = kwargs

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(**self.annotations)
```

Then we can add this manager to the `Salary` model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F

class Salary(models.Model):
    basic = models.IntegerField() 
    allowance = models.IntegerField() 
    incentives = models.IntegerField() 
    gratuity = models.IntegerField()
    _gross = None
    _ctc = None

    objects = AnnotationManager(
        gross=F('basic')+F('allowance')+F('incentives'),
        ctc=F('gross')+F('gratuity')
    )
```

We can also filter on these columns like:

```
Salary.objects.filter(gross__gt=100)
```

will retrieve all the `Salary` objects with `gross` larger than `100`. The filtering is here done at the database level, so not at the Python level. Django will translate the above in a query that looks like:

```
SELECT salary.*,
       salary.basic + salary.allowance + salary.incentives AS gross,
       salary.basic + salary.allowance + salary.incentives + salary.gratuity AS ctc
FROM salary
WHERE salary.basic + salary.allowance + salary.incentives > 100
```

Answer (score 5):

Its better to define `gross` and `ctc` as model methods or properties. Otherwise it will cause data redundancy. Also its better to use *snake_casing* for field names.

```
class Salary() :
    basic = models.IntegerField() 
    allowance = models.IntegerField() 
    incentives = models.IntegerField() 
    gratuity = models.IntegerField() 

    @property
    def gross(self):
        return self.basic + self.allowance + self.incentives

    @property
    def ctc(self):
        return self.gross + self.gratuity
```

Comment: Would add that you can wrap it into [`@property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods) if you want to preserve current API

Comment: This isn't working for me. How can I save "gross" or "ctc" in in it's own field in the model?

Answer (score 1):

[akhilsp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56198143/how-to-sum-django-model-fields/56198291#56198291) is spot on, you should compute these in model methods.

You can also compute these in the database.

```
salaries = Salary.objects.annotate(
    gross = F('basic') + F('allowance') + F('incentives'),
    ctc = F('gross') + F('gratuity')
)
```

You can even create a custom manager so that these are always computed:

```
from django.db.models import Manager, Model

SalaryManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset.annotate(
            gross = F('basic') + F('allowance') + F('incentives'),
            ctc = F('gross') + F('gratuity')
        )

class Salary(Model):
    ... # Other fields
    objects = SalaryManager()
```

Then any salary instance that was retrieved from the database using the ORM will have the `gross` and `ctc` attributes calculated already.

Comment: That's almost literally @WillemVanOnsem answer.

Comment: Gasanov, I think we answered at the same time. Or close enough that I started writing my answer before his was posted. Well, some validation of the idea at least, and it doesn't hurt to see a little variety in the implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=OfferLetter)
def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.gross_salary = instance.basic+instance.conveyance_allowance+instance.special_allowance
```

this one also working good

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is the best solution for you

models.py

```
class Salary() :
    Basic = models. IntegerField () 
    Allowance = models. IntegerField () 
    Incentivies = models.  IntegerField () 
    gross = models. IntegerField () 
    gratuity = models. IntegerField () 
     Ctc = models. IntegerField ()
```

views.py

```
def new_project():
    log = Salary.objects.annotate(
                Basic_num =Case(When(Basic='', then=0), default=Cast('Basic', FloatField()),
                           output_field=FloatField()),
                Allowance_num =Case(When(Allowance='', then=0), default=Cast('Allowance', FloatField()),
                               output_field=FloatField()),
                Incentivies_num =Case(When(Incentivies='', then=0), default=Cast('Incentivies', FloatField()),
                               output_field=FloatField()),
        ).annotate(
            avg_Basic_num=Sum(F('Basic_num')),
            avg_Allowance_num=Sum(F('Allowance_num')),
            avg_Incentivies_num=Sum(F('Incentivies_num')),
        ).annotate(
            total_avg_sum =F('avg_Basic_num') + F('avg_Allowance_num') + F('avg_Incentivies_num'),

    print(total_avg_sum)
```